# Querying a custom table does not return latest results for anonymous user

Tags: 8, database

I have a custom module and a simple custom table in the database. When I try to query the table to get the row, it seems Drupal 8, or maybe mysql, is caching the results.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();

$result = $connection->query("SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM {mytable} WHERE id = (:id)", [':id' => $key]);

$result->fetch()
```

We get the latest data if a I am  logged in to Drupal, but the data is cached if we are not logged in.

Comment: This is the page render cache, you can disable it with `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();`, but a better approach would be to define cache tags for the custom table.

Comment: Where would I put the \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger(); code?
I tried it in the construct of our controller and it didn't help. 
How would I define cache tags for the custom table?

Comment: Put the trigger in the controller where you query the database. For the tag based solution, which is better for performance, add a tag to the rendered output of the controller `$build['#cache']['tags'] = ['mytable'];` and invalidate it every time you write to the table `Cache::invalidateTags(['mytable']);`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to user drupal select instead of normal query something like following:

```
  // Add this use at the top of the file
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

  $connection = Database::getConnection();
  $query = $connection->select('mytable', 'my_table')
    ->condition('id', $key, '=');
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: True: however this won't solve his problem

Comment: Thanks, but as suggested, this doesn't solve the problem.
I need to get fresh data from the table even when a user is not logged in.